# Transit at Frankfurt Airport

Tags: transit, luggage, check-in, frankfurt, air-canada

I am travelling to Toronto, Canada on Tourist Visa from India.
My routing is from Delhi to Frankfurt on Air India and from Frankfurt to Toronto on Air Canada and returns YYZ to FRA on Air Canada and FRA to DEL on Air India.

I have query following query :

1. Do I need a transit visa at FRA airport?
2. Ticket will be issued on Air Canada documents, so will Air India tag by baggage till YYZ?
3. At Delhi Airport, do I have to go to the Air Indian check-in counter or Air Canada check-in counter?

Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need a transit visa at FRA airport?

You seem to have an overnight connection in Frankfurt. You might need a Schengen visa, if you'll be leaving the airport. For Indian citizens you'll need a transit visa to stay airside, unless exceptions apply. Having a Canadian visa is [one of the exemptions](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/2556510). See [here](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/2556510) or [here](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/services/travel-services/travel-and-health-restrictions.html) for details. The airport may not be open 24 hours, check the current updates (FRA *usually* is 24hrs open).

> Ticket will be issued on Air Canada documents, so will Air India tag by baggage till YYZ?

Yes.

> At Delhi Airport, do I have to go to the Air Indian check-in counter or Air Canada check-in counter?

Air India.

Comment: Indian citizens do **not** require a Airport Transit visa if they have a Canadian visa for onward travel within 24 hours after scheduled arrival in Frankfurt. [German Missions in India: Airport Transit visa - Federal Foreign Office](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/2556510): ***Exemptions**: a) Indian nationals holding a valid visa or residence permit from a member state of the Schengen area or Bulgaria, Romania, Croatia, Cyprus, Liechtenstein, Ireland, Canada, Japan, USA (except for holders of an US “Advanced Parole Document”)*

Comment: Frankfurt is open 24 hours.

Comment: @MarkJohnson ah, thanks, the doc I linked to only listed US visa for some reason. I'll update.

Comment: That is because your first (of 2) 'here' links was from the *German Missions in the United States*, thus is unlikely to contain specific infornation for Indian citizens.

Comment: @MarkJohnson oh you're right...

Comment: Frankfurt even has an [airside transit hotel](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/services/hotels/my-cloud-transit-hotel.html), though I'm not sure it can be reached from any non-schengen gate.

Comment: Further information: *MY CLOUD Transit Hotel is situated in the **non-Schengen area** at terminal 1, Gate Z 25. It is only accessible for guests whose travel route includes at least one non-Schengen flight. Rooms can be booked by the hour (from a minimum of 3h to a maximum of 24h). Check-in is possible between 5:00 and 22:00.*